# How can I find out the reason for a rejected SEPA "Lastschrift"?

Tags: european-union, transaction

I signed up for a service which is paid monthly, with a contract which went for one year and then auto-updates for another year if not canceled. The payment is done via SEPA Lastschrift (both I and the service are located in Germany).

For a year, everything went well, and I did not cancel. Suddenly, the thirteenth payment request was rejected by the bank, resulting in a rejection charge for my service provider. When I asked my bank to look into it, the first thing they did was to try to repeat the procedure, resulting in a second rejection and second charge.

After finally talking to a bank employee with some more knowledge, she suggested that I sign a new Lastschrift permission form, so the next payment will work properly. This will however not clear up why the process went awry in the first place.

I have a suspicion that my service provider will try to saddle me with the rejection charges. Our contract specifies that I have to carry them in case that there is not sufficient money on my account, but does not mention rejection for other reasons. So I am very interested in finding out why the whole thing did not work, especially whether it was a mistake by me, by my service provider, or by one of our banks.

The reason they have given me until now is "Gläubiger ID ungültig", invalid creditor ID. The lady from the phone banking said she does not have a way to check what happened.

What are my options for further pursuing the matter? Is there some entity which can find out what went wrong, and are they obliged or at least likely to give the information to me as an interested party?

Note that I'm not asking for legal advice, just wondering how can I obtain this information about a transaction involving my account.

Comment: "she suggested that I sign a new Lastschrift permission form" To what purpose? Under usual circumstances, none of the banks involved will see this permission form (mandate).

Comment: "Gläubiger ID ungültig" seems to me that either they have changed the creditor ID without updating their banking information, or that something else happened, all of them quite likely outside your control, so they should be in charge for all charges.

Comment: @glglgl Depends, B2B permissions are sent to the bank, they make it more difficult for the paying party to revoke a transaction. Regular B2C permissions don't go to the bank, of course.

Answer (score 3):

"Gläubiger ID ungültig" seems to indicate that the side trying to pull money from your account used a Gläubiger-ID that has expired or has been revoked.

(Just in case someone has the same question, two years later.)

Comment: From what I know of the UK Direct Debit system ("Lastschrift" = "Direct Debit"), it sounds like the service provider set up the initial direct-debit mandate incorrectly. For an "auto-update unless cancelled", I'd expect the original mandate to be open ended, but it sounds like they made it a fixed-term (12-month) mandate (and failed to renew it when the cancellation didn't happen).