# Can I find the duration of a SEPA "Lastschrift" permit I signed?

Tags: european-union, germany, transaction

If you need the background, you can read my [other question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/53768/how-can-i-find-out-the-reason-for-a-rejected-sepa-lastschrift). But I'm interested in answers to this one independently of the situation described there.

I allowed somebody to perform "Lastschrift" (take money from my account) regularly. If I kept a copy of the form I signed, I cannot find it. But I know that these permissions ("SEPA Mandat") have an expiry date.

Is there a way for me to find out when is the expiry date of the permission I signed? Will my bank know it, or the other person's bank, or some regulation institution?

Answer (score 1):

Your bank does not know about any SEPA Mandat you declare, until it gets in use.

When the optionees withdraw money from your Account, they have to authenticate with the given Mandat and at this point your bank knows about that Mandat wich has an expiry date.

According to the guidelines of the European Central Bank, your bank is not in duty to bookmark the expiration date.
However, I'd assume they do anyway due they are allowed to and it makes things easier.

Additional, if you can tell who the optionee is, you can block the withdraw before it happened.
In any case, you have to call your bank.